# How to get maximum and average of a field from mysql table with some conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with records like following.

```
id     score      student_id      course_id
----   ------     ----------      ----------
1      12         1               1
2      10         2               1
3      20         3               1
4      35         1               2
5      50         5               1
6      70         1               3
7      25         3               2
8      30         2               2
9      25         3               3
```

Currently i am running this query first

```
SELECT id,
       score,
       student_id,
       course_id
FROM scores
WHERE student_id=1
```

The output of the query is

```
id  student_id   course_id  score 
--  ----------   ---------  -----
1   1            1          12    
4   1            2          35    
6   1            3          70
```

THEN running LOOP ON RESULT AND finding avg_score, max_score USING this query

```
SELECT AVG(score) AS avg_score,
         MAX(score) AS max_score
  FROM scores WHERE course_id = RESULT['course_id']
```

and then adding them in the result. So finally i get the result with avg_score and max_score like this

```
id  student_id   course_id  score  avg_score  max_score
--  ----------   ---------  -----  ---------  ---------
1   1            1          12     23         50
4   1            2          35     30         35
6   1            3          70     47.50      70
```

I want to know if it is possible to get the result using a single query instead of as i am doing right now.

I have tried this query but i get only 1 row instead of 3. Also the avg_score and max_score are wrong.

```
SELECT Score.id, Score.student_id, Score.course_id, Score.score, ROUND(AVG(mScore.score),2) as avg_score, MAX(mScore.score) as max_score 
FROM `scores` AS `Score` 
LEFT JOIN `scores` as `mScore` ON mScore.course_id = Score.course_id 
WHERE Score.student_id = 1
```

Output of the above query is

```
id  student_id   course_id  score  avg_score  max_score
--  ----------   ---------  -----  ---------  ---------
1   1            1          12     30.78      70
```

sqlfiddle link is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a3f1f/8

If it is not achievable using single query but there is better alternative than what i am doing now, please let me know.

PS: Here is the jsfiddle link of actual problem.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c50aa9/1/0
It has two tables. I simplified and combined two table into one in the question.
The single query i was trying gives only one row where it should give 4 rows like this query without avg_score and max_score http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c50aa9/3/0

Comment: Could you pls provide sqlfiddle?

Comment: here is the sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c50aa9/1/0
the query gives only one row where there are 4 rows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c50aa9/3/0

Comment: I have solved the puzzle. I was almost there. Following query solved my problem

SELECT Score.id, Score.student_id, Score.course_id, Score.score, ROUND(AVG(mScore.score),2) as avg_score, MAX(mScore.score) as max_score 
FROM `scores` AS `Score` 
LEFT JOIN `scores` as `mScore` ON mScore.course_id = Score.course_id 
WHERE Score.student_id = 1 GROUP BY Score.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query solved the puzzle.

```
SELECT Score.id, Score.student_id, Score.course_id, Score.score, ROUND(AVG(mScore.score),2) as avg_score, MAX(mScore.score) as max_score 
FROM `scores` AS `Score` 
LEFT JOIN `scores` as `mScore` ON mScore.course_id = Score.course_id 
WHERE Score.student_id = 1 GROUP BY Score.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a3f1f/10

If still there is any better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, score, student_id, course_id,  
       AVG(score) as avg_score, 
       MAX(score) as max_score
FROM scores 
WHERE student_id = 1
group by id, score, student_id, course_id
```

And if you remove the `where` condition then you can get this for all students at once.

Comment: What is the $currentCourse stand for? Actually i meant current course_id is the course_id of each row of the result. Suppose for the the first row of the result, the avg_score and max_score is the average/maximum of all scores for course_id 1. For the second row it's for course_id 2.

Comment: Then try this modified query.

Comment: modified query does not work. it shows the score as avg_score and max_score. Check your query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a3f1f/11

Comment: BTW, I have solved the puzzle. I was almost there. Following query solved my problem 
SELECT Score.id, Score.student_id, Score.course_id, Score.score, ROUND(AVG(mScore.score),2) as avg_score, MAX(mScore.score) as max_score FROM scores AS Score LEFT JOIN scores as mScore ON mScore.course_id = Score.course_id WHERE Score.student_id = 1 GROUP BY Score.id
Thanks for your help.